# SQL relationships and best practices

Tags: sql, relationship

If I have a **User** table and a **Roles** table.

What is the usual **practice/pattern for adding the relationship**?

Do I create an extra column in the User table for the RoleID or do people usually create a Relationships table like so:

**Relationships Table**

```
RelationshipID | UserID | RoleID |... any other relations a user might have
```

for the last bit, as a user you might create an endless amount of different types of things that all need to be related to you... do you instead add the relationship to each individual table created for each individual thing.. for example:

**Pages Table**

```
PageID | Title | Content | Author (UserID)
```

and so another table would also be similar to this:

**Comments Table**

```
CommentID | Comment | Author (UserID)
```

In this case, I would need to expand upon the Relationships table if I were to do it that way:

**Relationships Table**

```
RelationshipID | UserID | RoleID | CommentID
```

and i'd probably only want to fill in the UserID and CommentID as this relationship is not for the Roles... that is governed by another entry. so for example the values might be put in for a comment relationship:

```
AUTO           | 2      | NULL   | 16
```

I could imagine a multi purpose Revisions table being handy...

**Revisions Table**

```
RevisionID | DateCreated | UserID | ActionTypeID | ModelTypeID | Status | RelatedItemID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1          | <Now>       | 3      | 4 (Delete)   | 6 (Page)    | TRUE   | 38
2          | <Now>       | 3      | 1 (Delete)   | 5 (Comment) | TRUE   | 10
3          | <Now>       | 3      | 1 (Add)      | 5 (Comment) | FALSE  | 10
```

but not for a general Relationships table...

Does this sound correct?

---

**Edit since comments:**
They stated that the relationships table should be made due to the many-to-many (data model)

---

So let's take my previous example of my possible relationship table:

**Relationships Table Old**

```
RelationshipID | UserID | RoleID | CommentID... etc
```

Should it actually be something more like this:

**Relationships Table New**

```
RelationshipID | ItemID        | LinkID     | ItemType    | LinkType | Status
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              | 23(PageID)    | 7(UserID)  | ("Page")    | ("User") | TRUE
2              | 22(CommentID) | 7(UserID)  | ("Comment") | ("User") | TRUE
3              | 22(CommentID) | 23(PageID) | ("Comment") | ("Page") | TRUE
```

Comment: If one user an have many roles and one role can be assumed by many users, you have a many to many relationship. You need the relationship table http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29

Comment: The relationshipId field is unnecessary.  Some people think it's a good idea to have one anyway.  I am not one of those people.

Comment: Can someone give me a demonstration as to what my relationships table might look like? I have given it a go in my OP (the bottom relationships table), does this look okay?