# What should a relationships table look like - Need confirmation of my technique

Tags: sql, relational-database

Lets say I have 3 models:

- User
- Page
- Comments

I asked a question based on if I should have each model keep track of its relationships: [SQL relationships and best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634016/sql-relationships-and-best-practices)

an example of this would be a "Pages" table that states who its author was... The problem seemed to be that if 2 users were the author of the one page, you'd have to add a new specific table called PageRelationshipsWithUsers that might have a reference to the PageID and the UserID that created it and a separate row for the co-author.

Understandably this sounds a bit naff. I would end up with a heck load of relation tables and most likely, it could be replaced with just the one multi-purpose relationship table... So I decided to come up with a relationships table like the following:

**Relationships Table New**

```
RelationshipID | ItemID        | LinkID     | ItemType    | LinkType | Status
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1              | 23(PageID)    | 7(UserID)  | ("Page")    | ("User") | TRUE
2              | 22(CommentID) | 7(UserID)  | ("Comment") | ("User") | TRUE
3              | 22(CommentID) | 23(PageID) | ("Comment") | ("Page") | TRUE
```

however, I would very much appreciate some input as to how good of an idea laying out my relationships table like this is.

Any thoughts?

**Answer was told to me by a work colleague:**

Imagine the above relationships table for the model "Book"

A User can Rent a book, so the relation is User -> Book...
But what if he can buy a book too: User->Book....

Ooops, we need a new relationship... and considering this relationship table was supposed to be the 1 size fits all, we now have a requirement to add a new separate table... whoops.

So the answer is NO NO NO. don't, it's naughty. Keep your relationship tables separate and specific.

Comment: If any of your "types" repeat, they should be in their own tables.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you've said. Do you mean that if there is 2 types of a Page. one with a Title and one with an AwesomeTitle... this is a rare case... am I wrong?

Comment: If you want to get to [3NF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), the repeating data that you have under types should have their own tables and then be referenced in your "relationship" table.

Comment: I have no repeating data in my table. The relationships table has 3 entries. 1 ) relates a page to a user (2) relates a Comment to a User (3) relates a Comment to a Page. I'm totally missing something here aren't I? lol

Comment: I see `("User")` twice under LinkType...

Comment: But taken into context, that relationship suggests that a page is linked to a user... and on a separate note... a comment is related to a user... and finally, a comment can be linked to a page (and is so in my example)? Could you elaborate a bit. Help me along with what you're suggesting. Would really appreciate it dude!

Comment: Having had to use such a schema over the past few years, can I strongly advise you *not* to do this. Keep the separate relationships in their own, appropriate tables and let the system maintain good referential integrity.

Comment: Is it due to performance? Did you use foreign keys to keep these relationships in check? Any good strong reasons? Understandably, 1 size fits all is not always the answer... but I really want to understand what issues people have come across.

Comment: James, you cannot have two foreign keys on a single column. You can't hvae one referencing User table and another referencing Page table. You'll have to split those two into two separate columns minimum. I would also advise not to go this route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your suggestion for a relationship table is not optimal for several reasons:

- It's difficult to write queries that join tables through the relationship table, as you will need filters on the ItemType and LinkType columns, which is not intuitive when writing queries.
- If a need arises to add new entities in the future, that use different datatypes for their primary keys, you cannot easily store ID's of various datatypes in your ItemID and LinkID columns.
- You cannot create explicit foreign keys in your database, to enforce referential integrity, which is possibly the best reason to avoid the design you suggest.
- Query performance might suffer.

When normalizing a database, you should not be afraid to have many tables. Just make sure to use a naming convention that makes sense and is self-documenting. For example, you could name the relation table between authors and pages "PageAuthors", instead of "Pages".

Comment: Although I do not agree with some of your points, having thought it over for some time now, I completely agree with the use of having case by case tables for relationships. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Is there a typical naming convention for a relationships table in SQL.. for example I will have a Page that needs to be authored by many users, so im going to create a table for "PageToUserRelations"... rather than this relatively ugly name, is there a usual naming convention for such a relationtable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631850/how-do-you-name-your-many-to-many-relationship-tables dw!